# Keyframe with Proportional Editing

Tags: graph-editor

I want to set a keyframe and have the neighbouring keyframes ease into that keyframe. How can I do that efficiently?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can click the *Proportional Editing FCurves* button or use the shortcut <kbd>O</kbd> and scroll your mouse to increase or decrease the affected area. You can also adjust the falloff with the *Proportional Editing Falloff* button to the right of the aforementioned button.

[image]

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when I keyframe it in the viewport, I need to move the keyframe back down, then proportionally edit back into location, which is a lot of clicks, and also inaccurate.

Comment: unfortunately no other way